# Uploading image from android to php server cpanel

Tags: php, android, cpanel

I'm trying to upload an `image` to a server. The server uses Cpanel. The files are not getting created in the server. This is the code

Android code.

```
    public static String uploadFile(String sourceFileUri, String fname){
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
        return null;
    }
    else
    {
        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL("http://sv-url/upload-files.php");

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=test;filename="
                            + fileName + "" + lineEnd);

                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            if(serverResponseCode == 200) {

            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();


            Log.e("Upload file to server", "Exception : "
                    + e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        return "http://sv-url/uploads/" + fileName;

    } // End else block
}
```

PHP Code:

```
enter code<?php

$file_path = "/home/sv-url/public_html/uploads/";

$file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
    echo "success";
} else{
    echo "fail";
}
?>
```

I also tried changing the file path to : `$file_path = "/uploads/";`
and to  `$file_path = "uploads/";` but the files are not getting created.

I can connect to the server from the phone and log data in the `mysql` database, the response code is 200 OK.

Comment: this should run in background thread. Try log on both side to see whether data reached to server or not

Comment: I put this logs `error_log("Upload File >>" . $target_path . $_FILES['error'] . " \r\n", 3,
    "Log.log");

error_log("Upload File >>" . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']) . " \r\n` and i'm getting Upload File >>uploads/20180110_233924_1284732291.jpg 
Upload File >>20180110_233924_1284732291.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The upload_max_file_size in php.ini was set to 2M, i set it to 100M.